# How to define special characters in string array java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need to define an array containing below all special characters..

```
+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \
```

I am using this

```
List<String> specialCharactersInSolr = Arrays.asList(new String[] {
                "+", "-", "&&", "||", "!", "(", ")", "{", "}", "[", "]", "^",
                "~", "*", "?", ":", });
```

It is accepting all the character except " and \

Please help how to define these two as well.

Comment: just escape them with a backslash! And why are you not using `Character` instead of `String`?

Comment: Exactly what I was about to type!

Comment: Use `"\""` and `"\\"` respectively. But you say you want characters here and define strings instead?

Comment: @jlordo. Probably because he also needs to store - `&&` and `||`.

Comment: In Java 5+ you do not need `new String[] { ... }`.

Comment: to google for this, try "escape characters java".

Comment: "It is accepting all the character" here "it" means the compiler. What error message did it give? Because that would have given you a clue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\` and `"` are special characters in String class

- `"` is start or end of String
- `\` is used to create some characters like new lines `\n` `\r` tab`\t` or to escape special characters like in your case `\` and `"`

So to make them literals you will have to escape them with `"\\"` and `"\""`

---

Other idea is to use `Character[]` instead of `String[]` so you wont have to escape `"` and yours characters can be written as `'"'` or `'\\'` (because `'` require escaping - it should be written as `'\''` - `\` is also special here and will also require escaping to produce its literal).

Comment: And in turn escape the backslashes as well.

Comment: @RohitJain this ain't regex. double backslash is how you write a single backslash

Comment: @RohitJain you are mistaken this will work fine.Try it your self

Comment: @Bohemian. Ah! right. Mixed it up with regex. Sorry. It'll work fine.

Comment: Ya i m not so active. But now i am trying to accept it. But it is not click able.

Comment: @TanuGarg Are you clicking tick under answer score? Do you have any error information saying why you cant accept answer?

Comment: @TanuGarg Maybe you have some AdBlock or other filters. Try refreshing page. If this wont help maybe try using other browser.

Answer (score 4):

Use this

```
List<String> specialCharactersInSolr = Arrays.asList(new String[]{
            "+", "-", "&&", "||", "!", "(", ")", "{", "}", "[", "]", "^",
            "~", "*", "?", ":","\"","\\"});
```

here `"\""` and `"\\"` are for `"` and `\`

Comment: Won't work. You need to escape the backslashes as well. This has to be done in Java.

Comment: @RohitJain wrong. this above code is fine. you thinking of how to write a literal backslash in regex maybe